# Split a file into no of small files in HDFS

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, split, hdfs

I have a file called `test.txt` in `HDFS`. It contains `1000` records.

I want to split the `test.txt` into 10 small files which contains same no of records.

I can do this in `Linux` like below

```
split -l $(($(wc -l < test.txt )/10 + 1)) test.txt
```

Is there a similar functionality in `HDFS`.

How can I achieve this in `HDFS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Hadoop Streaming job with the input format as `NLineInputFormat` can get this done.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-<version>.jar \
   -Dmapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap=10 \
   -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
   -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat \
   -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
   -input /test.txt \
   -output /splitted_output
```

Here the property `mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap` determine the number of lines each split must contain.